# MySQL Stored Function - How to get @@warning_count?

Tags: mysql, functions, mysql-8.0

I have the following MySQL 8.0 stored function:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION maybe_utf8_decode(str text charset utf8mb4, rowid INT)
RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
declare str_converted text charset utf8mb4;
declare max_error_count int default @@max_error_count;
set @@max_error_count = 0;
set @@max_error_count = max_error_count;
set str_converted = convert(cast(convert(str using latin1) as binary) using utf8mb4);
if @@warning_count > 0 then
INSERT INTO a_warnings (id) VALUES (rowid);
return str;
else
return str_converted;
end if;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

It gets executed like this:

```
UPDATE products SET description2 = maybe_utf8_decode(description,id);
```

I got this function from here: https://jonisalonen.com/2012/fixing-doubly-utf-8-encoded-text-in-mysql/ . The purpose is to fix our database by correcting "double encoded" product descriptions. The problem is that a plain CONVERT by itself truncates many of my product descriptions when it encounters an Error or a Warning. The function above isn't working because it's not recognizing Warnings/Errors when `convert(cast(convert(str using latin1) as binary) using utf8mb4)` is attempted. My plan was if a Warning/Error appeared, skip the conversion script and save the product id instead, so I can review them manually. Otherwise if there are no Errors/Warnings, I would like the function to convert the string.

What would be the proper way to write this function, so it skips strings if Errors/Warnings appear and store that rowid in a separate table?

Example of warning that I want to skip. When I run:

```
convert(cast(convert(description2 using latin1) as binary) using utf8mb4)
```

I'll occasionally get an warning like below, followed by my string getting truncated:

```
Warning: #1300 Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'A04C69'
```

I would like my function to rollback that conversion and return the original string when a Warning like that happens (to prevent my data from being truncated). *So the problem is how do I know a warning like this happens in my function? How do I get @@warning_count to work the way I intend?*

Answer (score 0):

Use user-defined variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION maybe_utf8_decode(str text charset utf8mb4, rowid INT)
RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
-- ...
if @@warning_count > 0 then
    INSERT INTO a_warnings (id) VALUES (rowid);
    SET @warnings_amount := @warnings_amount + 1;    -- increase UDV
    return str;
else
    return str_converted;
end if;
END
```

and then

```
UPDATE products 
  JOIN (@warnings_amount := 0) reset_UDV   -- init/clear UDV value
SET description2 = maybe_utf8_decode(description,id);

SELECT @warnings_amount;   -- look for warnings amount collected in UDV
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The problem is that I'm having trouble getting the `@@warning_count` in the if/then statement. It seems that the function is unable to tell when a Warning/Error happens, so it just skips to the `else` part by default. I know Warnings exist, but `@@warning_count` is not recognizing them for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had basically the same problem with the same function: the check against `@@warning_count` just wasn't reliable. I don't know if it was a race condition or what, but that was my best guess.

I changed the function to use a handler for the 1300 error code instead and that resolved the issue:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION maybe_utf8_decode(str longtext charset utf8mb4) 
RETURNS longtext charset utf8mb4 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
declare str_converted longtext charset utf8mb4;
declare exit handler for 1300 return str;

set str_converted = convert(binary convert(str using latin1) using utf8mb4);
return str_converted;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This doesn't have the "rowid" portion and saving of problem rows into another table that your original does, but that could be worked into the exit handler also.